# How to pass bypass Options request in spring webflux security?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, spring-webflux

I have created a spring webflux security class to enable security with custom authentication and authorization filter.

```
  public SecurityWebFilterChain securityWebFilterChain(ServerHttpSecurity http) {
    log.debug("Configuring tenant web security");

    return http
        .cors(Customizer.withDefaults())
        .csrf().disable()
        .authorizeExchange()
        .pathMatchers(HttpMethod.OPTIONS, "/**").permitAll()
        .pathMatchers(new String[]{"/api/demo"}).permitAll()
        .anyExchange().authenticated()
        .and()
        .addFilterAt(authenticationWebFilter(), SecurityWebFiltersOrder.AUTHENTICATION)
        .addFilterAt(authorizationWebFilter(), SecurityWebFiltersOrder.AUTHORIZATION)
        .build();
  }
```

Here Authenticaion filter is:

```
   /**
   * Method to get the instance of {@link AuthenticationWebFilter}.
   *
   * @return {@link AuthenticationWebFilter} instance.
   */
  private AuthenticationWebFilter authenticationWebFilter() {
    AuthenticationWebFilter authenticationWebFilter = new AuthenticationWebFilter(
        customAuthenticationManager);
    authenticationWebFilter.setServerAuthenticationConverter(customAutenticationConverter);
    NegatedServerWebExchangeMatcher negateWhiteList = new NegatedServerWebExchangeMatcher(
        ServerWebExchangeMatchers.pathMatchers(new String[]{"/api/demo"}));
    authenticationWebFilter.setRequiresAuthenticationMatcher(negateWhiteList);
    return authenticationWebFilter;
  }
```

Authorization web filter is:

```
 private AuthorizationWebFilter authorizationWebFilter() {
    return new AuthorizationWebFilter(customAuthorizationManager);
  }
```

Cors Configuration is:-

```
  @Bean
  public CorsConfigurationSource corsConfigurationSource() {
    CorsConfiguration corsConfiguration = new CorsConfiguration();
    corsConfiguration.addAllowedOrigin("*");
    corsConfiguration.addAllowedHeader("*");
    corsConfiguration.addAllowedMethod(HttpMethod.OPTIONS);
    UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource corsConfigurationSource = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
    corsConfigurationSource.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", corsConfiguration);
    return corsConfigurationSource;
  }
```

Now when I make the OPTIONS request it still goes to my `customAuthenticationManager` which I have registered above in filter.

How can I bypass this?

Comment: Its because when you add custom filters all bets are off. Why use a security framework when all you do is writing everything custom? (Which i might add is bad practice)

Comment: Custom filter was needed because for each request thier is a header x-auth-token which I then use against my auth server to verify the token and then only pass the authentication.

Comment: why arn't you customizing the already default implemented filters in spring security that the framework is providing you? as i said, custom security is bad practice, and when using custom filters, you are basically opting out of the framework and all its features.

Comment: I am customizing `AuthenticationWebFilter` only by giving it my custom `AuthenticationManager` and `ServerAuthenticationConverter`

Comment: no you are not, you are creating a completly new AuthenticationWebFilter, and setting it in the filter chain manually. You are not customizing the current one, which you should do by supplying a @Bean to the context that gets picked up by the current filter.

Answer (score -1):

The `corsConfigurationSource` bean worked for me. There was the problem with request that I was hitting

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.